# Split and merge the table cells

Tags: tables, split

I want to create the following type of table for my paper.

[image]

How can I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: For horizontal rules not across the whole line you can use `\cline{4-7}`. To merge cells horizontally you can use `\multicolumn{<count>}{<align>}{<contents>}`. To merge cells vertically you can use `\usepackage{multirow}` and `\multirow{<count>}{<width>}{<contents>}` (use `*` for `<width>` to use the contents' natural width).

Comment: Please clarify what it is about the table  shown in the screenshot that you wish to reproduce. Maybe the centering of the letter "F" above 6 columns? The irregular column widths? The fact that the contents of almost all cells are left-aligned? Please be specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recreating your table (but with only natural width columns) you can use the following to get the lines like in your example:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{10}{l|}}
  \hline
  A & B & C & D & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{F} \\
    &   &   &   & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{}  \\
  \cline{5-10}
    &   &   &   & a & b & c & d & e & f \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
  \hline
  1 & 1.1 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \hline
  2 & 1.2 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \hline
  3 & 1.3 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: ugly results]

**But:** it is considered bad typography to use tables with vertical rules and too many horizontal ones, therefore I'd advice to use the rules provided by `booktabs` and that you read [`booktabs` documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) (there are a lot of helpful tips concerning good looking tables):

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand\vcenterhead[1]
  {%
    \multirow{2}{*}[-0.5\dimexpr\aboverulesep+\belowrulesep+\cmidrulewidth\relax]{#1}%
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{10}{l}}
  \toprule
  \vcenterhead{A} & \vcenterhead{B} & \vcenterhead{C} & \vcenterhead{D} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{F} \\
  \cmidrule(l{.5\tabcolsep}r{.5\tabcolsep}){5-10}
    &   &   &   & a & b & c & d & e & f \\
  \midrule
  1 & 1.1 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  2 & 1.2 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  3 & 1.3 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: booktabs results]